# Extract data from multiple XMLs into a single Excel document (1 row per xml)

Tags: xml, excel, extract

I have 1000+ xml files, I need to iterate through the xml files selecting the specified data pieces and insert them into a single row per file in a single excel document (1 row per xml file).

All xml files are in the format below...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<simpleXMLResult xmlns="http://sdk.prometric.com/schemas/SimpleXMLResults1_3" version="1.3">
-<demographics workstationname="T003" functioncode="41472" appointmentid="0000000076499080">
<demographic value="SHRMAPP860" name="ClientID"/>
<demographic value="USA" name="Country"/>
</demographics>
-<exam workstationname="T003" functioncode="41472" name="SCP" countmarked="0" countskipped="0" countincorrect="39" countcorrect="111" count="150" restartcount="0" duration="11006" enddatetime="2015-05-27T10:37:18" startdatetime="2015-05-27T07:33:51" driverversion="8.9.2 Build #0 (UTD 8.9 CORE (A))" examformname="Form4" resourceversion="2.0" resourcefilename="41472.cer">
<score scorecut="0" scoremax="150" scoremin="0" passindicator="p" scoredisplay="111.00" scorevalue="111"/>
-<sections>
<section name="scnConfirm" countmarked="0" countskipped="0" countincorrect="0" countcorrect="0" count="0" duration="34" enddatetime="2015-05-27T07:34:29" startdatetime="2015-05-27T07:33:52"/>
-<section name="scnNDA" countmarked="0" countskipped="0" countincorrect="0" countcorrect="0" count="0" duration="17" enddatetime="2015-05-27T07:34:49" startdatetime="2015-05-27T07:34:30">
-<itemgroup name="NDA.1" duration="17.691" visited="1" presented="1" weight="1" progid="UTDP.MultiChoiceItem.1" scored="0">
<item scoremax="1" scoremin="0" marked="0" skipped="0" complete="1" scorenom="0" score="1" correctresponse="A" response="A"/>
</itemgroup>
</section>
-<section name="scnForm4" countmarked="0" countskipped="0" countincorrect="39" countcorrect="111" count="150" duration="10260" enddatetime="2015-05-27T10:37:18" startdatetime="2015-05-27T07:41:36">
<score scorecut="0" scoremax="150" scoremin="0" passindicator="p" scoredisplay="111.00" scorevalue="111"/>
-<itemgroup name="F4_1" duration="87.11" visited="3" presented="1" weight="1" progid="UTDP.MultiChoiceItem.1" scored="1">
<item scoremax="1" scoremin="0" marked="0" skipped="0" complete="1" scorenom="0" score="1" correctresponse="C" response="C"/>
</itemgroup>
-<itemgroup name="F4_2" duration="19.796" visited="1" presented="1" weight="1" progid="UTDP.MultiChoiceItem.1" scored="1">
<item scoremax="1" scoremin="0" marked="0" skipped="0" complete="1" scorenom="0" score="1" correctresponse="C" response="C"/>
</itemgroup>
-<itemgroup name="F4_3" duration="28.314" visited="1" presented="1" weight="1" progid="UTDP.MultiChoiceItem.1" scored="1">
<item scoremax="1" scoremin="0" marked="0" skipped="0" complete="1" scorenom="0" score="0" correctresponse="D" response="B"/>
</itemgroup>
-<itemgroup name="F4_4" duration="45.724" visited="1" presented="1" weight="1" progid="UTDP.MultiChoiceItem.1" scored="1">
<item scoremax="1" scoremin="0" marked="0" skipped="0" complete="1" scorenom="0" score="1" correctresponse="D" response="D"/>
</itemgroup>
-<itemgroup name="F4_5" duration="35.772" visited="1" presented="1" weight="1" progid="UTDP.MultiChoiceItem.1" scored="1">
<item scoremax="1" scoremin="0" marked="0" skipped="0" complete="1" scorenom="0" score="1" correctresponse="D" response="D"/>
</itemgroup>
</section>
</exam>
</simpleXMLResult>
```

I would like the data to look like this per Row... Since i cant post images i will try to write it out.

```
A1 = <exam> name ("SCP")
B1 = <demographic> value where name = "ClientID" in this case ("SHRMAPP860")
C1 = <exam> examformname ("Form4")
* For the rest of the columns there could be a dynamic number
D1 = <item> response ("A") ** There could be 5 of these or 100 depending on the xml file, I need each one put into its own column
E1 = <item> response ("C")...
F1 = ""
```

I have tried using the XML mapping built into Excel but it did not seem realistic since i have over 1000 xml files and was finicky trying to get the format that i needed the data in. I some VBA experience and have written macros before. My main problem is how to get the data out of all the xml files and into a working form that i can do something with.
What do you guys suggest is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe this should be a wiki question

Comment: I am still new to stack overflow what is a wiki question and how do i make mine into one?

Answer (score 0):

I've used PHPexcel with awesome results in very complex and unpredictable excel sheets. It's a very simple api and you get powerful results in little time.

Link to documentation:
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation